# Can not write slash into file in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write simple string into file which should contain backslash, when I print on the screen backslash is there but when write into file using fwrite it is removed. I have try double, quadruple escape it still doesn't work

```
$key="Hello";
$trs ="This place is 'too cool'";
$removed = str_replace("'", '\\\\\'', $trs);
if($removed!=$trs){
     echo $removed."<br>";
}
fwrite($file, "'$key' => '".$removed."'" . ",\n");
```

When run the code I will get - `This place is \\'too cool\\'`
But when the same value is written to the file I will get `This place is 'too cool'`

Comment: `fwrite` doesn't make any changes to the data, so this isn't possible.

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: It looks like you're writing PHP code to the file. If you're executing the file as a PHP script, the backslashes will escape the quote, and not show up when you view the variable. You need to write two backslashes to the file.

Comment: Opening in text editor

Comment: basically 'key' => 'value \' other data ' should be printed

Comment: I just tested this. When I opened the file in a text editor, it contains **'Hello' => 'This place is \\'too cool\\'',**

Comment: what version of php?

Comment: version 5.6.30 on Mac

Comment: I am on php 7.3.7 on mac too. makes no sense

Comment: I just upgrade to 7.1.32, still works as expected

Comment: this is super strange, I am gonna quick reinstall and see what happen

Answer (score 0):

If the backslash \ is required as a character and should not be an escape sequence,  \x5C can  be used in double quotes.

```
$removed = str_replace("'", "\x5C\x5C'", $trs);
```